# RewriteRule same name as directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For my site I have a directory called `/test/`. I want to rewrite `www.example.com/nl/test` and `www.example.com/nl/test/` to a certain page (`test.php`).

#### Some global conditions (for all the rules)

```
RewriteRule ^(nl|en)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [NC,R]
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(nl|en)$ $1/ [NC,R]

RewriteCond $1 !^(en|nl)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ en/$2 [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(nl|en)/(.*)$ $2?language=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^sale$ sale.php
RewriteRule ^valentine$ valentine.php
```

#### Some conditions for the rewrite + folder

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ test.php
```

The redirect of `www.example.com/nl/test/` is correct. The language parameter is also correctly rewritten.

For the second redirect (the version without the trailing slash) I can't get this working.

```
RewriteRule ^test$ test.php
```

Now my URL is rewritten as `www.example.com/test/?language=nl`

Can someone give me a tip or hint to fix this? I can't change the name of the directory since there are several external URLs linking to this directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will do the whole job (instead of 4 lines you have there): it will rewrite both `/nl/test` and `/nl/test/` to `/test.php?language=nl`.

```
RewriteRule ^(en|nl)/test/?$ /test.php?language=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

### NOTES:

The `[QSA]` flag will preserve any existing query string (therefore, there is no need for `&%{QUERY_STRING}`).

---

### Full .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(nl|en)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(en|nl)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /en/$2 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(nl|en)/(.*)$ /$2?language=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^sale/?$ sale.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^valentine/?$ valentine.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [QSA,L]
```

### NOTES:

There is no need for `RewriteRule ^(nl|en)$ $1/ [NC,R]` as you already have `RewriteRule ^(nl|en)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [NC,R=301,L]`. It does the same job.

Comment: This doesn't cope with `^test/?$`, though.

Comment: @Chris What do you mean? The URLs provided by OP show that there will be `en/` or `nl/` in front.

Comment: For the other rewriterules i have i don't add the (en|en) since i added this first line `RewriteRule ^sale$ sale.php` this results in rewrite ^sale$ to /nl/sale.php. This probably won't work since there is a directory with the same name...

Comment: @PimPee TBH I'm confused now. I, obviously, do not know how your whole app works and what other rules you have in place. You asked to rewrite 2 specific URLs (`www.xxx.com/nl/test` and `www.xxx.com/nl/test/`) to another (`test.php`). My rule will do this job just fine. It would be good if you provide more information (update your question, include your .htaccess in full) so that rule can be rewritten if necessary.

Comment: @PimPee See my updated answer: I took the content of your .htaccess and reorganized it a bit. I have tested the `/nl/test/` (where `WEBSITE_RROT/test` is the real folder) .. and it works fine on my setup. The pattern `^test/?$` will work for both `/test/` and `/test`.

Comment: @lazyone My server currently runs apache 2.2.8 support for the DPI flag is added in version 2.2.12. Is the script affected if i remove these flags (DPI). The url is still rewritten to /test/?language=nl :(

Comment: @PimPee I see. No problem -- replace it `DPI` by `L` and add `DirectorySlash Off` directive. It will be slightly slower (as it will do whole iteration from the top), but will work (well .. work on my 2.2.17).